# How do I horizontally center multiple rotating span elements in a div?

Tags: html, css

I was playing around with the code snippets from https://codepen.io/amritleone/pen/qERPmW. Disclaimer: I have read questions on stackoverflow about centering spans but this case is slightly different. The span elements are rotating with fade in animation.

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>A Community of</h1>
 <div class="fadeIn">
  <span>Aardvark</span>
  <span>Bee</span>
  <span>Caterpillar</span>
  <span>Doggo</span>
  <span>Elephant</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS so far. **I used text-align for div and display: inline-block for spans. However,the spans seems like they are aligned not at the center but a point starting from the center.**  I have included a picture for visual reference.
[image: Reference pic]

Bee is not at the center.I am not very articulate with English but please ask me if my description is not clear enough.

```
.fadeIn{
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
.fadeIn span{
animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
-webkit-animation: fadeEffect 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
font-family: ubuntu;
font-size: 25px;
opacity: 0;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

/*FadeIn Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes fadeEffect{
0% { opacity: 0; }
5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
80% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect{
0% { opacity: 0; }
5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
80% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fadeEffect{
0% { opacity: 0; }
5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
80% { opacity: 0; }
100% { opacity: 0; }
} 
.container{
height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for a start, I'd remove the `position: absolute;` from the `.fadeIn span{}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Normally, removing 'position: absolute' will help but, in this case, it makes all spans appear at different locations instead of where I wanted.